# Repository is full! Is there a way to reduce space used up by git LFS?

Tags: git, gitlab, repository, git-lfs

we are a games developing studio and unfortunately we hit out LFS storage size limit of 10Gb. Now, I wonder and have trouble finding out about how to reduce the size of the stored LFS files as much as possible.

As of now, our artists cannot work due to the repository being "full".

As far as I understand, garbage collection and prune-commands do not help much, because all LFS file versions are referenced somewhere in some commits in our git history.

At the same time, we have thousands of commits, so it's not really doable to squash our history, or is it?

I'd be fine with losing all the history of our LFS files to free up space, again. But unfortunately, I do not know how to do this, if it is doable at all.

Any suggestions?